# How to write condition based variable in SCSS

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

In this below example the xyz will be dynamic value and consider it as a variable, the same need to use it as selector.

```
body.user-$xyx {
  div.employee-$xyx{
    display: none;
  } 
}
```

So that i can hide the element thats in my user id.

```
<body class="user-2">
  <div class="employee-1"></div>
  <div class="employee-2"></div> // will be display none
  <div class="employee-3"></div>
</div>
```

How do i write that using SCSS?

Answer (score 0):

### Example 1

The `#{$user-id}` syntax is used for variable interpolation to insert the value of `$user-id` into the selector.

**The Code:**

```css
$user-id: 2;

body.user-#{$user-id} {
  div.employee-#{$user-id} {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<body class="user-2">
  <div class="employee-1"></div>
  <div class="employee-2"></div> <!-- will be display none -->
  <div class="employee-3"></div>
</body>
```

When compiled, this SCSS code will generate the following CSS:

```
body.user-2 {
  div.employee-2 {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

### Example 2

If the `$user-id` is dynamic and can change for each user, you can use SCSS mixins and a loop to generate the styles (check *resources* section below).

**The Code**

```
@mixin hideEmployee($user-id) {
  body.user-#{$user-id} {
    div.employee-#{$user-id} {
      display: none;
    }
  }
}

@for $i from 1 through 3 { 
  @include hideEmployee($i);
}
```

When compiled, this SCSS code will generate the following CSS:

```
body.user-1 div.employee-1 {
  display: none;
}

body.user-2 div.employee-2 {
  display: none;
}

body.user-3 div.employee-3 {
  display: none;
}
```

### Example 3 (without SCSS)

In the examples above, we had to declare the number of the `employees`, in case the number is known.

Now, in this example, we generate the dynamic CSS using the `generateCSSRules` function and append them as a `<style>` element to the `<head>` of the document. The `generateCSSRules` function dynamically generates the CSS rules based on the the number of employees.

**The Code**

```js
var employees = document.querySelectorAll('div[class*="employee"]');
var employeesLength = employees.length;

const generateCSSRules = (employeesLength) => {
    var css = '';
    for (var i = 1; i <= employeesLength; i++) {
        css += `body.user-${i} div.employee-${i} {display: none;}`;
    }
    return css;
}

var style = document.createElement('style');
style.innerHTML = generateCSSRules(employeesLength);
document.head.appendChild(style);
```

```html
<body class="user-2">
  <div class="employee-1">1</div>
  <div class="employee-2">2</div>
  <div class="employee-3">3</div>
</body>
```

This will add the following styles to `<head>`:

```
<style>
    body.user-1 div.employee-1 {display: none;}
    body.user-2 div.employee-2 {display: none;}
    body.user-3 div.employee-3 {display: none;}
</style>
```

#### Resources:

[Sass | @for](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/for) 
[Sass | @mixin and @include](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin) 
[Sass | Interpolation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation)

Comment: But $user-id: 2; supposed not to be defined. As this is for the application where the user-id will be changing for each of them.

Comment: Based on what? Where you get the value from?